# are non singleton beans not a prototype in spring

Tags: spring

I was reading the documentation for SmartFactoryBean and was intrigued by the documentation saying that isPrototype is just not the inverse of isSingleton

and any scoped beans are not prototypes.

Is this because they are not truely independent? and what do we mean by not truely independent.

what is the rationale behind this?

I could not get convincing answer my self and hence turned to the experts at sof.

Vam

Comment: There are other scopes, not just singleton and prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype is dealing with **independent** instances, that is every time you ask for the bean basically you get a different instance. Singleton is about giving you the exact same instance every time you asked for it.

`Prototype` and `singleton` are one of the **scopes** that Spring support. It supports many other scopes namely `request`, `session`  (for the HTTP request and session, respectively), `step` (for a Spring Batch step), etc. You can even [create your own](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-custom)

What the doc basically states is if `isPrototype` returns `false`, that does not mean that the bean is a singleton as it can be bean attached to the HTTP session for instance.

[The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) provides more details on this subject.